# How to import an Azure publishsettings file to an Angular project using Visual Studio Code on mac?

Tags: angular, azure, web-applications, visual-studio-code, web-deployment

I've built an Angular application with Visual Studio Code and I've been instructed to deploy it to Azure using a .publishsettings file that has been provided.
My attempts at accomplishing this have failed. Do I require anything besides the .publishsettings file and an Azure account in order to deploy the web app?
Most tutorials I've found online are for regular Visual Studio.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Adding a bit more info I posted in a comment, so it doesn't get lost:

I've successfully deployed to a new, freshly created Azure app on my Azure dashboard. The thing is, I need to deploy my Angular app to an already created Azure app, to the clients' account. Hence why I was supplied with the .publishsettings file.

Comment: Install in vs code the Azure App Service extension

Comment: This is something I forgot to mention, I had already installed the Azure App Service extension. But where exactly can I import the publishsettings file? I have managed to publish my Angular application to a freshly created Azure App Service. But I see no way of using the publishsettings file to deploy it to an already existing Azure App Service, that happens to belong to another user.

Comment: Vs code doesn't have integrated buid system like VS. Usually you can work with command line.

Comment: I tried using the Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile on the Azure PowerShell, but it requires you to mount a storage which incurs in a monthly fee. So that's a no deal. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You also could follow this [tutorial](https://briandesousa1.wordpress.com/2018/07/30/deploy-angular-app-from-vs-code-to-azure/) to publish angular app to azure webapp which you have created without publishsettings file. Because you could select **Yes** on the `Are you sure you want to deploy…` dialog to **overwrite any previous deployments you may have done to your Azure Web App**.

Comment: That tutorial is fine, and I've successfully deployed to a new, freshly created Azure app on my Azure dashboard. The thing is, I need to deploy my Angular app to an already created Azure app, to the clients' account. Hence why I was supplied with the .publishsettings file.
So far, I see no way of accomplishing that with Visual Studio Code, which is kind of mind boggling as, from what I can tell, it's the preferred editor of the front end community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I tried using the Azure App Service extension, this proved to be unfruitful.

I also attempted to transfer the project to Visual Studio Community, as it seemed to be relatively easy to import the publish.settings into it. However, the Mac version doesn't seem to have this functionality.

Ultimately, the method that worked for me was the following:

- Opened the publish.settings file and got the FTP host, login and password from it.
- Installed a third party FTP client and used the previous information to manually upload the web app build folder to the desired destination.

I believe that the client could have given permissions to my Azure account in order to upload directly from Visual Studio Code, with the use of Azure App Service extension. But if they are unwilling or incapable of doing so, the FTP method seems to be the only way to achieve the same result.